# How to localize a list of months in rails with I18n

Tags: ruby-on-rails, localization, rails-i18n

I've this code:

```
<%=options_for_select((1..12).map {|m| [Date::MONTHNAMES[m], m]}) %>
```

How I can localize i with I18n?

Already tried with `I18n.l` without luck

Comment: Did you try this? http://findnerd.com/list/view/How-to-get-all-month-names-in-the-current-locale-in-Rails/13524/

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me is:

```
<%=options_for_select((1..12).map {|m| [t('date.month_names')[m], m]}) %>
```